# Using AJAX to get SharePoint group user names?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, groups, html, ajax

Very often Ajax is used to get list items, delete them, update them etc.

I want to know how I can use ajax to get the usernames of a specific SharePoint group. (Just printing them on the console is enough for me)

This is what I've got, but it doesn't work out, because it tells me `The property "results" of an undefined or null reference could not be called.` What am I doing wrong? I tried using DOM Explorer to look up the HTML as well and I was able to figure out in which `div` the username was written, but don't know what to write in the code.

```
function getSPGroupUserInfos() {

    NWF$.ajax({
            url: "sites/bm/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=9",
            type: "GET",
            headers:
               {
                   "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
               },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log("dataresults: " + data.d.results);
                var dataresults = data.d.results;
                for (var i = 0; i < dataresults.length; i++) {
                console.log("User Title - " + dataresults[i].Title);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log("Failed");
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Check the answer to this question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264090/rest-api-retrieve-group-members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below SharePoint REST endpoint to get the group Members from specific group:

Considering name of your group is `BM Members`,

```
_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetByName('BM Members')/users
```

To get the specific property for user, you can add `$select` query as given below:

```
_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetByName('BM Members')/users?$select=Email,Id
```

Check my full answer given at: [REST API - Retrieve Group Members](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264090/rest-api-retrieve-group-members)